# npm nodejs project with typescript; live build doesn't recompile changed modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I found a description to init a nodejs project in typescript here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html

This also describes a way to autorecompile onchange, if I run a code using npm start.

I created a project with this configuration:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2015",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
     "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
  },
  "files":[
    "server.ts",
    "db/db.ts",
    "protocol/protocol.ts"
  ]

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:live",
    "build:live": "nodemon --exec node_modules\\.bin\\ts-node -- server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.36",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.20",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

The reload works fine, if I change the mainfile server.ts

**Problem**

If I change db.ts or protocol.ts, the reload is performed, but db.ts and protocol.ts are not recompiled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using nodemon and ts-node to do dev, instead I would recommend using [tsc-watch](https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch).

`npm install tsc-watch --save-dev`

And in your `package.json` you should do this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./build/server.js\"",
  }
```

- `build` is for building your app to be ready for production.
- `start` just for starting your app on production.
- `dev` is for compiling and then running/re-running node.

**REMARK:**
Script can then be run using "npm run dev"

Comment: Thanks, could you describe, why you would not use ts-node?

Comment: ts-node compiles all the ts files, watch for changes and serve them to a new instance on node, this is not very good for production use.
ts-node is nice to have for testing.